# How to get total workers by button?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

my requirement like this 
when i adding workers in select workers tree view, then need to add total of them right side bottom total workers field.its ok its show when i'm going to save or when i clicked the **(update)** button.
i refer the purchase module but i can't find what function exaclty called when that button clicked.

my whole code uploaded to [here@GitHub](https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp.git)
refer line 397 in bpl_view.xml and line 335 in bpl.py

as per purchase module i wrote function.but its have only return statement.thats also confused to me.

```
def button_total(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    return True
```

please advice me on this issue & please tell me why when clicked the button records save automatically.?its have only return True statement. ? ?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code:

```
def button_total(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    tea_worker_line_ids = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context).selected_tea_workers_line_ids or []
    total_tea_worker = len(tea_worker_line_ids)
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'total_workers': total_tea_worker}, context=context)
    return True
```